# AngularJS injector

Tags: angularjs

Can anyone give a detail example of injector of AngularJS.
Here is the code copy from API.
"In the following example a new block of HTML containing a ng-controller directive is added to the end of the document body by JQuery. We then compile and link it into the current AngularJS scope."

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
</body>
<script>
   angular.module('myApp', []);
var $div = $('<div ng-controller="formController">123</div>');
$('body').append($div);
angular.element(document.body).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
  var scope = angular.element($div).scope();
  $compile($div)(scope);
});

function formController ($scope,$http) {
}
</script>
```

I copy and paste it in a html page, but it does not work.with error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

UPDATE:
I have included jquery, and got a new error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'invoke' of undefined

Comment: You need to include jQuery.

Comment: Have you included jQuery in your project?

Comment: Thanks, I modified it, but got a new error msg.

Comment: include jquery *before* angularjs

Comment: @pixelbits, already changed it, but the error still exists

Comment: `var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();` use this in the beginning then use `j$` for all the jquery operations and `$` for all angular operations

Comment: I post a snippet,hope anyone can help me fix the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an angular module -- angular.module('myApp', []);
2. Update the body element to use this module -- `<body ng-app="myApp">`
3. Give some time for angular to bootstrap the application.

   ```
   setTimeout(function () {
       // now you can use the injector.
       var $div = $('<div ng-controller="formController">123</div>');
       $('body').append($div);
       angular.element(document.body).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
           var scope = angular.element($div).scope();
           $compile($div)(scope);
       });
   }, 100);
   ```

Your example should work with these changes.

Comment: I have never use AngularJS before. I modified as you said, but it does not work, could you help me check whether my modification is wrong, or there still exist other error

Comment: Updated the answer. If it still doesn't work, please increase the timeout provided to the timeout function and try.